# Are there any countries that impose the death penalty for being in the country illegally?

Tags: capital-punishment, illegal-immigration

I'm referring to simply being in the country without authorization, or having entered illegally; what is called in the US "undocumented", and which most countries treat with deportation.

ChatGPT tells me that Saudi Arabia and Iran execute people for "immigration-related offences" such as drug trafficking, so that doesn't count yet.

Comment: ChatGPT is a completely untrustworthy source on all legal topics.

Comment: @ohwilleke what do you base that on? I haven’t used it much but would have thought it could be quite useful as a starting point. Of course not to be ultimately trusted / relied upon, but if it gives you the names of ideas/constructs that can be further researched, or if it gives authorities that can be consulted directly for corroboration I’d expect it to be quite useful. Granted, “chatGPT said” is not a whatsoever valid legal citation.

Comment: It will give you theories and principles that you can further research, but they are not reliable. I have repeatedly attempted to use it for legal research, and it has given me demonstrably false information every time.

Comment: @Seekinganswers ChatCPT has a particularly high "hallucination" and incorrect answer rate in legal topics. It is not a useful starting point. I've seen people try to do that and it is just awful. It makes up fake cases most of the time that it cites to cases at all. It argues rules of law that don't apply or don't exist. It misses good arguments. It is worse than useless in its current form.

Comment: @Seekinganswers "if it gives you the names of ideas/constructs that can be further researched, or if it gives authorities that can be consulted directly for corroboration I’d expect it to be quite useful": if it did that, it might be useful.  But it doesn't do that.  It gives you the names of cases that do not exist.  Try searching for ["Varghese v. China Southern Airlines"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Varghese+v.+China+Southern+Airlines%22).  Also drug trafficking is not an immigration-related offense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there any countries that impose the death penalty for being in the
> country illegally?

No.

Sometimes illegal immigrants are denounced as "spies" which can be a death penalty offense in places like North Korea. But illegal immigration *per se* is not a death penalty offense in any country having immigration-type laws. (There are some basically un-contacted tribes in the Andaman Islands or the Amazon or Papua New Guinea that kill strangers on sight without any legal process.)

Comment: You don’t say it directly but you do seem to insinuate that the denunciations are without reasonable basis / unfounded. Do you have anything solid or even anything at all to base that on? I don’t think that anti-US “axis” states generally tend to be as erratic or irrational as they are often made out in the media to be.

Comment: For example I remember looking into the “hikers” case (Sarah Shourd et al) apprehended by Iranian authorities and remember thinking that it was quite unreasonable the way that they were being portrayed in the media as totally innocent: their affiliations that I found I remember finding quite suspicious and gave the impression of CIA (or similar) assets.

Comment: Also, are there any remaining countries in the world that don’t have “immigration type laws”?

Comment: @Seekinganswers "You don’t say it directly but you do seem to insinuate that the denunciations are without reasonable basis / unfounded." I am insinuating no such thing. Some countries denounce a significant percentage of illegal immigrants as spies, but in those countries it might very well be true. I certainly don't know one way or the other.

Comment: @Seekinganswers "Also, are there any remaining countries in the world that don’t have “immigration type laws”?" Parts of Greenland. Some stateless territory near the border of Sudan. Maybe other places i don't know about. My main goal was to distinguish areas where communities not legally recognized as states that are un-contacted exist.